# Is there a reason git commit --no-verify would still run hooks?

Tags: git, macos, git-commit

I am currently attempting to commit a WIP branch that breaks the hooks on my project. Executing this command:

```
git commit --no-verify -a -m "Issue #1149: get past second error"
```

... results in Git running commit hooks.

I do have a workaround:

```
git -c core.hookspath=/dev/null commit -a -m "Issue #1149: get past second error"
```

But can anyone propose something about my local setup that would cause this to happen?

```
$ git version
git version 2.39.2 (Apple Git-143)
```

This happens under both VSCode terminals and `Terminal.app` (I wanted to rule out some sort of strange VSCode behavior related to their shell integration).

Comment: [`git commit --no-verify`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--n) skips `pre-commit` and `commit-msg` hooks. All other hooks go: `prepare-commit-msg`, `post-commit`.

Comment: Fascinating! I assumed it was the pre-commit hook that was running, it did not occur to me to look further into the hooks setup. Will try that now.

Comment: That's it. The project implements the hooks in terms of its own code, so since my refactoring has broken everything, the thing can't run even those hooks. I'll use the workaround for now. Thanks a bunch, @phd!

Comment: Does your project use [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) or a similar library?

Comment: No, it writes its own shell scripts into a hooks directory and uses those.